# CarouselView with a different template for each slide in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, templates, xamarin.forms, carousel

I need to make a CarouselView in Xamarin forms where every slide has a specific template.
Currently I have done so:

**XAML**:

```
xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
.......

 <ContentView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <control:CarouselView x:Name="carouselView">
            <control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding Testo}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
          </control:CarouselView>
        </ContentView>
```

**CODEBEHIND** :

```
List<CustomCell> myCarousel = new List<CustomCell>();
myCarousel.Add(new CustomCell { Testo = "ciao" });
myCarousel.Add(new CustomCell { Testo = "ciao due" });

carouselView.ItemsSource = myCarousel;
```

**CustomCell**:

```
public class CustomCell
{
    public string Testo { get; set; }
}
```

All this works, my problem is that I'd have a different template for each slide, for example, a grid different graphically each slide, this is because I have to display data differently graphically speaking.
Can you recommend a solution? Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [data template selector](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/data-templates/selector/) to customize the look of different items in the CarouselView. A simple example:

**MyDataTemplateSelector.cs**

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate SimpleTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ComplexTemplate { get; set; }

    public MyDataTemplateSelector()
    {
        SimpleTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(SimpleView));
        ComplexTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ComplexView));
    }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        CustomCell cell = (CustomCell)item;

        if (cell.Testo.Length > 5) {
            return ComplexTemplate;
        } else {
            return SimpleTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

SimpleView.xaml

```
<ContentView>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
      <Label Text="{Binding Testo}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

ComplexView.xaml

```
<ContentView>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow" >
      <Label Text="{Binding Testo}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
      <Label Text="I lied about this being complex" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

And in the page where your CarouselView is:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"></local:MyDataTemplateSelector>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

....

<control:CarouselView x:Name="carouselView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
```

Comment: Problem: CarouselView doesn't expose a field called "ItemTemplate". Can you adjust your example to demonstrate how to properly assign that property?

Comment: CarouselView does expose that property... It just doesn't show up in Intellisense if you have a `<cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate />` node in your document already.