# Using CarouselView with a different template for each slide in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datatemplate

I need to make a CarouselView in Xamarin Forms where every slide has a different DataTemplate.

What I have tried:

DataTemplateSelector.cs:

```
    class DataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate MatchEventsTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate CommentsTemplate { get; set; }

        public DataTemplateSelector()
        {
            MatchEventsTemplate = new MatchEventsTemplate(typeof(MatchEventsUC));
            CommentsTemplate = new CommentsTemplate(typeof(CommentsUC));
        }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

MatchEventsUC.XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FodboldApp.View.UserControl.MatchEventsUC">
    <ContentView .Content>
        <flv:FlowListView x:Name="flowListView" FlowColumnCount="1" Grid.Row="1"
                                  SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True" 
                                  FlowItemsSource="{Binding EventList}" BackgroundColor="White" >
            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.005*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding PlayerName}" Grid.Column="{Binding Team}" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="{Binding Team, Converter={StaticResource teamConverter}}"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="{Binding Team, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" Grid.Column="2" HeightRequest="20" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

CommentsUC.XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FodboldApp.View.UserControl.CommentsUC">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <flv:FlowListView x:Name="flowListView2" FlowColumnCount="1" 
                                  HasUnevenRows="True" HeightRequest="180"
                                  FlowItemsSource="{Binding CommentList}" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Black">
            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid RowSpacing="5">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding UserName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Margin="0,10,0,5" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding UserComment}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

In the page where I add the CarouselView:

```
<control:CarouselView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
```

My problem is that I don't know how to control which template has to be shown (`OnSelectTemplate`). How to I switch between the templates with a slide? I have got the idea to use a data template selector from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41716975/4108238). What I want to achieve is to show two different listviews.

Answer (score 0):

Because the content is static, you don't really care about the items' data. So you can just bind List to the CarouselView, and use them as an index.

In your ViewModel define a property:

```
public List<int> Items { get; set; } = new List<int>() { 0, 1 };
```

Bind this property to your CarouselView:

```
<control:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
```

And in your OnSelectTemplate you can check for the index:

```
    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
         var index = int.Parse(item.ToString());
         switch(index)
         {
             case 0:
                 return MatchEventsTemplate;
             case 1:
                 return CommentsTemplate;
         }
         throw new Exception($"The template {index} isn't implemented")
    }
```